# Placing a window exactly in front of another hwnd

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I have two window handles (both of which don't belong to my process) and I need to place one hwnd exactly in front of the other.

One method would be to bring one window to front, then the other.
The problem with this is that the two windows are now also in front of other windows, but I don't want that.

What I'd need is the ability to increase the Z order of a hwnd by exactly one.
Or some other way to reorder the windows from my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pinvoke [`SetWindowPos()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) and use the `hWndInsertAfter` parameter.

Comment: When I set the target window behind my "overlay" window it causes problems with other windows. Other windows will still be between the overlay and the target window... If there would be something like "hWndInsertBefore" maybe it would solve the problem.